# The uploaded image not displayed after ajax upload in chrome

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome, ajax-upload

I did an ajax upload with php.Everything wiil be perfect in firefox.

But when i test it in chrome browser its not working correctly.

That means it displays this :
[image]

This is my ajax upload code:

```
$(function(){
        var cntUp = 0;
        var btnUpload=$('#upload0');
        var status=$('#status');
        var state='left_front';

        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'upload-file.php',
            data: {saleid: $("#hid_saleid").val(),imag_state:state,custom:$('#custom').val()},
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // extension is not allowed 
                    alert('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                    return false;
                }
                this.setData({
                    'saleid': $("#hid_saleid").val(),
                    'imag_state':'left_front',
                    'custom':$('#custom').val()
                });

                status.text('Uploading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                var array_data=response.split('***');   
                var  fname= array_data[1];  
                var rand=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); 
                var saleid = $("#hid_saleid").val();
                var custom = $('#custom').val();
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('image uploaded');
                cntUp++;
                //console.log(cntUp);
                //Add uploaded file to list
                if (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") >= 0 ) {
                    var image='<img src="uploads/'+saleid+'/'+fname+'" alt=""  width="131px" height="125px"/>';
                    $("#img0").html(image);

                }  else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
                    //alert('error');
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="brwse_box">
<div style="float:left;" id="upload0">
<h3>Left Front</h3>

<img src="images/upload.gif" />
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:131; height:125" id="img0">
<?php if($l_ft==''||$l_ft==NULL) { ?>
  <img src="images/no-photo-lft-frnt.jpg"  id="bg"/>
<?php } if($l_ft!=''||$l_ft!=NULL){?>
   <img src="uploads/<?php echo $var_sid;?>/<?php echo $l_ft;?>" id="bg" width="131px" height="125px"/>
<?php }?>
</div>
</div><!--browse_box ENDS-->
```

How can i solve this?

It displaying image in firefox.but in chrome not displaying image instead of that displaying html of image tag.

EDIT:

This is the value return in `fname` variable:

`left_front.jpg<div id=isChromeWebToolbarDiv" style="display:none"></div>`

Comment: check value of `saleid` and `fname` `src="uploads/'+saleid+'/'+fname+'"`

Comment: `<div id=isChromeWebToolbarDiv" style="display:none">` is caused by a Chrome extension called **DVDvideosoftTB** Disable `DVDvideosoftTB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem in the src string.
Check it for escape characters...
I'd say it's possible that `fname` contains quotes...

EDIT:
[What "isChromeWebToolbarDiv"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074334/what-ischromewebtoolbardiv)

```
fname = fname.replace(new RegExp("<div id=isChromeWebToolbarDiv(.*)</div>"),'');
```

or simply

```
fname = fname.replace(new RegExp("<div(.*)</div>"),'');
```

Comment: @Armel this is the value of `fname` return `left_front.jpg<div id=isChromeWebToolbarDiv" style="display:none"></div>`

Comment: You're using DVDvideosoftTB chrome extension?

Comment: @Armel i dont what is that?how can i chacek that using?

Comment: See Edit in my post. It's a Chrome extension. Just type DVDvideosoftTB or isChromeWebToolbarDiv in google

Comment: @Armel this the only extension in my chrome `BrotherSoft Extreme 2.3.15.10`

Comment: @Armel so what i tell to customer if he check it in another location?

Comment: @Armel in my chrome i can handle this by disbaling the extension,but what the client or customer do if they get this error...?

Comment: I'd say you're not responsible for this bug... If you want to correct it you should test the fname string and clean it for chrome with a regexp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16221/discussion-between-armel-l-and-mariya-davis)

Answer (score 1):

after your **EDIT** on question, it came to know that

is coming in  `src`

This is caused by a Chrome extension called **DVDvideosoftTB**. It appears to append the above HTML to file upload requests. You can easily disable it:

- Click on the Wrench icon
- Click "**Tools**"
- Click "**Extensions**"
- Disable DVDvideosoftTB

Comment: this is the only extension in my chrome `BrotherSoft Extreme 2.3.15.10`

Comment: in my chrome i can handle this by disbaling the extension,but what the client or customer do if they get this error...?

Comment: you have to put a sidenot on the page to handle this