# Ajax Editor: Image not displayed in chrome

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax Editor. During copy paste from a already prepared DOC file I am able to view all the contents of the file in the editor in IE and FireFox.
The problem is with chrome, I am able to get the text but the image goes blank or a transparent box appears with broken image icon in it.                           I referred the post on 
   [The uploaded image not displayed after ajax upload in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257914/the-uploaded-image-not-displayed-after-ajax-upload-in-chrome) but it was of no use.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsL7.png)

[Please click here to view the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsL7.png)